# Is there a way to have a number string type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I would like to define a type for arbitrary strings of numbers like "123", "0", "1234923874".

I know that I could define a multi digit type as a single-digit types like so:

```js
type digit = "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9";
type multiDigitStr = `${digit}${digit}${digit}${digit}${digit}${digit}`;
```

But then I get an error

`Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.ts(2590)`

Further, the above type is limited to 6 digits where I might not know how long the string is.

Trying to use regex to describe one or more string numbers as a type has unexpected results:

```js
type multiDigitStr = `${digit}+`;
let a: multiDigitStr;
a = "123412341";
```

Produces this error:

`Type '"123412341"' is not assignable to type '"0+" | "1+" | "2+" | "3+" | "4+" | "5+" | "6+" | "7+" | "8+" | "9+"'`

---

Is it possible to create a multi-digit string type?

Comment: Why do you need such type? To validate form values? We usually keep them as numbers with min max and regex validations

Comment: I am trying to parse a JSON that has a predictable format from a website. One of them is numbers in strings, and this type would be more specific than a generic string type.

Comment: Kind of https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160#issuecomment-714018457 but it's probably not something that should be typed if it's dynamic

Comment: Thank you! I've been able to adapt this so that function parameters can be checked as a number string (linked example was hex string). It doesn't seem that there is a way to adapt this to variables though.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a multi-digit string type

No.

## More

Would be possible if TypeScript supported Regex Validated string types : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160